# Any chance to repair corrupted MOV file?

Tags: file-corruption

I have a MOV file with Cineform raw codec that got corrupted due to power loss
of my camera. I tried any program to repair it, but no success.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Grau Video Repair](http://grauonline.de/). It's a commercial software, but the demo version lets you recover half of the file, so you can verify if it works with your video before purchasing {*}. It's quite simple to use, you have to load the file that you want to repair, and a normal / complete / healthy video made with the same device, to provide the program with a sample of the data patterns to identify. It works well with MP4 / AVC or MOV / AVC videos, when the missing index makes the whole file unreadable ; if you're lucky it could repair that type of video format as well.

{*} There is a simple workaround to get the whole file even with the demo, but you'll have to search on your own ! :^p